# css design changes device to device

Tags: jquery, css

I have developed game like match the following using jquery animate function.Its working perfectly what i expected.Here is my game http://jsfiddle.net/Manivasagam/z4aLva34/40/. My problem is, when i run this game in my system its working fine like below image,
[image]

But when i run in other system, its alignment automatically changing(maked in black) like below image,

[image]

**css** what i am using,

```
#main{ width: 800px; border: 1px solid #f00}

#first {

    float:left; /* add this */

    height: 350px;
     padding-left: 0px;
}
#second {
    text-align:left;
   float:right;
     height: 350px;
}

.dropzone {

margin: 5px;
padding: 10px!important;
border: 2px dashed #f0ad4e;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #eeeeee;
z-index: 50;
float: left;
text-align: center;

list-style:none;
}


 .item {

    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px!important;
    border: 2px solid #5bc0de;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    z-index: 9999;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    list-style:none;
    }

    label, span { position: relative; }
```

**jsp:**

```
<div  id="main" align="center">
<div id="first" class="nav nav-justified">      
     <label id="Cat" class="dropzone">Cat</label><br><br><br>
     <label id="Snake" class="dropzone">Snake</label><br><br><br>
     <label id="Cow" class="dropzone">Cow</label><br><br><br>
     <label id="Afor" class="dropzone">A for</label><br><br><br>

     <label id="Cfor" class="dropzone">C for</label><br><br><br>

 </div>
    <div id="second">
        <label id="Cow" class="item"  name="Milk">Milk</label><br><br><br>        
         <label id="Cat" class="item"  name="Rat">Rat</label><br><br><br>  
          <label id="Snake" class="item"  name="Eagle">Eagle</label><br><br><br> 

               <label id="Cfor" class="item"  name="Cherry">Cherry</label><br><br><br> 
                   <label id="Afor" class="item"  name="Apple">Apple</label><br><br><br> 
 </div>
   </div>
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: sorry I did not read carefully, I was expecting to show pop up on the center, I removed my answer

Comment: @MehmetErenYener Its ok i understand.tell me solution if u know.

Comment: I tried with chrome, firefox, IE but there is no problem with it that you mentioned in the picture. Trying to figure out

Comment: @MehmetErenYener not often but that alignment problem comes sometimes.

Comment: @MehmetErenYener I guess why the problem is, the animating element comes out from its own div after animated.but i dont know how to fix?

Comment: @manivasagam have you tried your fiddle on your "other system"? It seems to be working for me.. [See?](http://i.imgur.com/skFFrUX.png)

Comment: @manivasagam Try this on your system if it works as you want i will add it as answer http://jsfiddle.net/z4aLva34/42/

Comment: @RandomUser its working fine in windows system but problem arising in linux system only.

Comment: @Tambo ok i check and let you know.

Comment: @manivasagam *"other system"* is very vague. It's working fine for me. Which browser, what version..?

Comment: @TJ i am running the page using tomcat sever so my system server system.working fine in my system but this problem comes to client system which is running the page.

Comment: @TJ this problem comes only in linux based system not windows system.!

Comment: @Tambo Its working fine so please add your answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Demo on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4aLva34/42/)

```js
$(function(){
var count=0;
  var click=0;
  var i=1;
 $('#textid').val('');
 $('#textid2').val('');
 //$('.item').prop('disabled','disabled');
 
$('#successMessage').hide();
$("#errorMessage").hide();

$('.dropzone').attr('Disabled',false);
$('.item').attr('Disabled',false);

$('.dropzone').click(function(){
 var x,y;
 var Ans = $(this).attr('id');
  
 $(this).animate({left:"250px"},"slow" );

 //$(this).effect("highlight", {});
 //$(this).blink();
 
   T  = $("#"+Ans).offset().top;
   L = $("#"+Ans).offset().left; 
  // alert('x :'+T+'\n'+'y :'+L);
 //var lname = $(this).attr('name');
 $('#textid').val(Ans);
 var textval=$('#textid2').val();
 //alert(textval);
 //$('#textid2').val(lname);
 
 if(textval!=""){
  //alert(Ans+'\n'+'#'+textval);
  $('#'+textval).animate({left:"0px"},"slow" );
  
  }
 $('#textid2').val(Ans);
 
 //alert('#'+Ans);
 //$('label[name='+lname+']').animate({right:"200px"},"slow" );
 //alert(Ans);

 
});

$('.item').click(function(){
 
 var Ques =$(this).attr('id');

 var lname = $(this).attr('name');
 $(this).animate({right:'250px'});
 var Ans =$('#textid').val();
 var text2 =$('#textid2').val();

 if(text2=="")
   {
   
    $(this).animate({right:"0px"});
   }
  
 //alert(lname);
  var T  = $("#"+Ans).offset().top;
  var L = $("#"+Ans).offset().left;  
  // alert('x :'+T+'\n'+'y :'+L);
 
   
  
 //alert('label name :'+lname);
 if(Ques==Ans)
 {
       //alert("matched");
       M  = $(this).offset().top;
      N = $(this).offset().left;
      M-=T;
      N-=L+120;
     
     //alert(M+"\n"+N);
      $(this).animate({bottom:M+'px'});
      $(this).animate({right:N+'px'});

      var isimagecheck=$('#imageyestext').val();
     // alert(isimagecheck);

       if(i==1){

          
   
   $("#"+Ans).css({'background-color':'red','color':'white'});
   if(isimagecheck=="no"){
   $('input[name='+lname+']').css({'background-color':'red','color':'white'});
   }
   else
   {
    $(this).css({'background-color':'red','color':'white'});
   }
   }

   else if(i==2){
    
   $("#"+Ans).css({'background-color':'green','color':'white'});
   
   if(isimagecheck=="no"){
    $('input[name='+lname+']').css({'background-color':'green','color':'white'});
    }
    else
    {
     $(this).css({'background-color':'green','color':'white'});
    }
   }
   else if(i==3){
    
    $("#"+Ans).css({'background-color':'yellow','color':'black'});
    if(isimagecheck=="no"){
     $('input[name='+lname+']').css({'background-color':'yellow','color':'black'});
     }
     else
     {
      $(this).css({'background-color':'yellow','color':'white'});
     }
    }
   else if(i==4){
    
    $("#"+Ans).css({'background-color':'gray','color':'white'});
    
    if(isimagecheck=="no"){
     $('input[name='+lname+']').css({'background-color':'gray','color':'white'});
     }
     else
     {
      $(this).css({'background-color':'gray','color':'white'});
     }
    }
   else if(i==5){
    
    $("#"+Ans).css({'background-color':'pink','color':'white'});
    
    if(isimagecheck=="no"){
     $('input[name='+lname+']').css({'background-color':'pink','color':'white'});
     }
     else
     {
      $(this).css({'background-color':'pink','color':'white'});
     }
    }
else if(i==6){
    
    $("#"+Ans).css({'background-color':'#339933','color':'white'});
    
    if(isimagecheck=="no"){
     $('input[name='+lname+']').css({'background-color':'#339933','color':'white'});
     }
     else
     {
      $(this).css({'background-color':'#339933','color':'white'});
     }
    }
else if(i==7){
 
 $("#"+Ans).css({'background-color':'pink','#666633':'white'});
 
 if(isimagecheck=="no"){
  $('input[name='+lname+']').css({'background-color':'#666633','color':'white'});
  }
  else
  {
   $(this).css({'background-color':'#666633','color':'white'});
  }
 }
else if(i==8){
 
 $("#"+Ans).css({'background-color':'pink','#CC9900':'white'});
 if(isimagecheck=="no"){
  $('input[name='+lname+']').css({'background-color':'#CC9900','color':'white'});
  }
  else
  {
   $(this).css({'background-color':'#CC9900','color':'white'});
  }
 }

       $('input[name='+lname+']').prop('disabled',true);
       $("#"+Ans).attr('disabled',true);
     $(this).attr('disabled',true);

       $('#textid2').val('');
       $('#textid').val('');
       count++;
  i++;
        
  

       
 }
 else
 {
  $("#" + Ans).animate({left:"0px"});
        $(this).animate({right:"0px"});
        $('#textid2').val('');
        $('#textid').val('');
        click++;
        
 }

 function successMessagestyle()
 {
  $('#successMessage').animate( {
        left: '550px',
        top: '180px',
        width: '400px',
        height: '110px',
        opacity: 1
      } );
 }

 function errorMessagestyle()
 {
  $('#errorMessage').animate( {
        left: '815px',
        top: '180px',
        width: '350px',
        height: '110px',
        opacity: 1
      
      } );
 }

 if(count==5)
 {
  $("#successMessage").show();
  $("#successbuttonid").blink();
  $("#successbuttonid").css({'color':'green'});
  successMessagestyle();
 }

 if(click==6)
 {
  $("#errorMessage").show();
  $("#errorbuttonid").blink();
  $("#errorbuttonid").css({'color':'red'});
  errorMessagestyle();
  $('.item').attr('disabled', true);
  $('.dropzone').attr('disabled', true);

 }


 
});





});

function PlayAgain()
{

 $("#errorMessage").hide();
 
 location.reload(true);

}





//blink jquery plugin


(function($)
{
 $.fn.blink = function(options)
 {
  var defaults = { delay:500 };
  var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
  
  return this.each(function()
  {
   var obj = $(this);
   setInterval(function()
   {
    if($(obj).css("visibility") == "visible")
    {
     $(obj).css('visibility','hidden');
    }
    else
    {
     $(obj).css('visibility','visible');
    }
   }, options.delay);
  });
 }
}(jQuery))
```

```css
*{box-zizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0}

.dropzone {
    z-index: 50;
    border: 2px dashed #f0ad4e;
}
.item {
    z-index: 9999;
    border: 2px solid #5bc0de;
}

label, span { 
    position: relative;
}
label{
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    text-align: center;
    list-style:none;
}
#main{ width: 800px; border: 1px solid #f00; position: relative}
#first,#second{height: 350px;}
#first {
    float:left; /* add this */
    padding-left: 0px;
}
#second {
    text-align:left;
    float:right;
}


#successMessage {
  position: absolute;
  left: 580px;
  top: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #dfd;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: .3em .3em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  padding: 20px;
}

#errorMessage {
  position: absolute;
  left: 580px;
  top: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #dfd;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: .3em .3em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  id="main" align="center">
<div id="first" class="nav nav-justified">  
     <label id="Cat" class="dropzone">Cat</label>
     <label id="Snake" class="dropzone">Snake</label>
     <label id="Cow" class="dropzone">Cow</label>
     <label id="Afor" class="dropzone">A for</label>

     <label id="Cfor" class="dropzone">C for</label> 

 </div>
    <div id="second">
        <label id="Cow" class="item"  name="Milk">Milk</label>         
         <label id="Cat" class="item"  name="Rat">Rat</label> 
          <label id="Snake" class="item"  name="Eagle">Eagle</label> 
    
               <label id="Cfor" class="item"  name="Cherry">Cherry</label>  
                   <label id="Afor" class="item"  name="Apple">Apple</label>  
 </div>
   </div>                              
       
<input type="hidden" id="textid" value="" >
<input type="hidden" id="textid2" value="">  
    
    
      <div id="successMessage" align="center">
    <h2 id="successbuttonid">You did it!</h2>
    <button id="" onclick="PlayAgain()">Play Again</button>
  </div>

<div id="errorMessage" align="center">
    <h2 id="errorbuttonid">Sorry! You Lost! You cliked 6 times wrong answer</h2>
    <button id="" onclick="PlayAgain()">Play Again</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its problem is on Firefox. Your `AFor` div has a problem.

```
<label disabled="disabled" style="background-color: yellow; color: white; bottom: 57.6px; right: 351.6px;" id="Afor" class="item" name="Apple">Apple</label>
```

When I remove and add again `right` position, it will work good. So, you can update your CSS via jQuery.

Comment: I am animating and adding css through jquery only.